# How To: Animation in Corona SDK

Tags: animation, coronasdk, ios-animations

I want to create a game using Corona SDK and have done so before but without the use of any kind of animation. This time, as you might have guessed, I need to learn how to animate!

What exactly am I looking for? What a mighty fine question!

I need some software that will allow me to create multiple pictures (profile view) of a man running and pictures that will allow me to simulate a moving sky. I am open to any and all suggestions!

Also, if you could tell me as to how I can write an animation function in Corona, that would be awesome.

Comment: choose which is useful for you:
①Use `transition` for simple animation
②Use `graphics.newImageSheet()` `display.newSprite()` and `myAnimation:play()` for simple animation
③Use `Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", func)` and display object (with attribute like `obj.x` `obj.y` `obj.alpha`) for complicated key-frame animation

Comment: @Albert do you know of any software that will allow me to create different pictures to create the animation?

Comment: Google "Texture Packer" may help you.